# Cannot return values, if method body is included from another php file?

Tags: php, include

I'm building a class, which has some of its methods' bodies defined in other php files.
I have to do this, because although most functions are small, sane, and written by hand, a couple functions need to be auto-generated by another script I made.
The problem is that although the methods get called, the return statements in those methods don't seem to execute.
The general structure is like this:

**MyClass.php:**

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
        include "myclass-foo-body.php";
    }
}

?>
```

**myclass-foo-body.php:**

```
<?php

echo "foo()"; // This executes and outputs as normal.
return 42; // This does not appear to actually execute or return anything.

?>
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php

include_once "MyClass.php";
$bar = new MyClass();
$foo = $bar->foo();
var_dump($foo); // Ends up being NULL instead of 42.

?>
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?
Are function/method bodies not actually supposed to be included from another php file?
I appear to have followed the documentation for [php's include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), but I seem to be missing crucial information.
(I couldn't find any existing questions on this subject, so hopefully this isn't a dupe!)

Thanks!

Comment: There should never really be any need to include logic like this within a class.... if it needs to be included in sevarel methods, then you use a helper class so it's defined in the one place; if your code is writing code, then use closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return value of your body file will be the return value of your include call so you should do it like below.

```
    public function foo()
    {
       return  include "myclass-foo-body.php";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `foo` is not returning anything.

A `return` in the included file terminates the processing of the included file.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file
>   in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script
>   which called it.